# Is there any suggestion to my shell script that (un)mounts an ISO file in order to make it better and safer?

Tags: shell-script, mount, iso, unmounting

I wrote a script to `mount` / `umount` an iso file by detecting whether the `/media/iso-file-name` exists.

Any suggestion for the script as below in order to make it better and safer?

```
#!/bin/bash

Mountpoint="/media/$(basename "$*")"

if [ -d "$Mountpoint" ]
then
    while [ -d "$Mountpoint" ]
    do
        umount "$Mountpoint"
        rmdir "$Mountpoint"
        sleep 3
    done
else
    mkdir "$Mountpoint"
    mount -t iso9660 -o loop "$*" "$Mountpoint"
fi
```

Comment: Why do you want to sleep for 3 seconds?

Comment: @Thushi If the device is busy, then it cannot be `umount`ed immediately, so `sleep 3` can make sure that all data in buffer write into the destination properly. (I don't want to use lazy unmount (`-l` option) because that may damage the filesystem.)